# Ajax function is not being triggered

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a problem with my AJAX function which is not being triggered. It seems like I'm doing everything fine but for some reason it's not triggered when the select box is changed:

Here is my Ajax function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showSections(id){
if (id=="")
{
    document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML="";
    return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("MyDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getRets.php?sem=" + id, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
 </script>
```

here is the select box:

```
<select name='sub' id="sub" onchange="showSections(this.value)">
<option value="1">Pending</option>
<option value="0">Performed</option>
</select>
<div id="MyDiv">
   some data
</div>
```

This is the gerRets.php file:

```
<?php
 $numbVal = $_GET['sem'];
 echo $numbVal;
 ?>
```

Can anybody point out to me my mistake? Apparently I just don't see it.

Comment: What does your debug console tell you?

Comment: nothing just no reaction at all

Comment: the content of the div stays the same as before

Comment: Maybe we should use the jquery ajax functions?

Comment: this is the most rediculus part. the ajax is not being prompt and no mistake is shown

Comment: @user3383116 please NEVER include the entire framework just to make a simple AJAX request...

Comment: @meks where is this script tag? In body or head? Before this select or after?

Comment: its in the head. Before the select box

Comment: Everything appears to be in order its just function is not being triggered

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a6pTS/ - this is your code and it works...

Comment: `</script>` closing tag is missing - do you have it in your source?

Comment: Yes I do. I didn't put it because there are some other functions

Comment: Why on earth it is not working in my page if it works in fibble?

Comment: what can possibly hinder ajax execution?

Comment: Syntax error in other functions in the same `script` block?

Comment: hold on I will remove other functions exept this one

Comment: I removed every other Javascript from the page but the problem persists. I'm already at my wits' end

Comment: can a php mistake affect it?

Comment: But to be honest there are no visible php mistake as long the page works normally

Comment: cna I put the whole page's code?

Comment: or it will be too clumsy?

Comment: my select box is within form tag. Can It affect it?

Comment: i think you may have lots of divs with the same id, `MyDiv`

Comment: Thank you elmo. You were correct there wes a link to an javascript file with an error. I removed it and its working ok. Thank yuo

Comment: Sorry lads. totally my fault.

Comment: I've had a problem like this before, try jQuery ajax out... I did and I'm a big fan. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/